# Using textalk/websocket-php to connect with socket.io

Tags: php, websocket, socket.io

I've a problem with connecting to [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/) server using [textalk/websocket-php](https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php) package

On the node(WebSocket) side I've:

```
server = httpServ.createServer().listen(process.env.PORT);  //3000
let socketCorsConfig = {
    origin: "*:*"
}
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    path: '/ws',
    serveClient: false,
    pingInterval: 10000,
    pingTimeout: 5000,
    cookie: false,
    cors: socketCorsConfig
});
io.use(async (socket, next) => {
    console.log('middleware');
    ...
});
io.on('connection', async socket => {
    console.log('connection, socket: ' + socket.id);
    ...
});
```

On the PHP(Symfony) side I've:

```
use WebSocket\Client as WSClient;
...
$wsClient = new WSClient('ws://php-websocket:3000/ws/?EIO=4&transport=websocket');
while(true){
    $message =  $wsClient->receive();
    dump('Data', $message);
}
$wsClient->close();
```

In the console the output is:

```
Data 0{"sid":"H3I27EP0LH-JOJWvAAAI","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":10000,"pingTimeout":5000,"maxPayload":1000000}
Data 
Data 0{"sid":"nIij79dNorR_kYxOAAAJ","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":10000,"pingTimeout":5000,"maxPayload":1000000}

In Connection.php line 464:
                       
  Client read timeout
```

Response indicates that PHP Client was able to reach the WS server and received the [handshake](https://socket.io/docs/v4/how-it-works/#handshake). Unfortunately it failed to establish permanent connection.

Do you have any suggestions on what might be the problem here?

I should also mention, that there's no problem with connecting to WS server using [socket.io client](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Client+read+timeout+php probably relevant

Comment: And even if you didn't reach that, the http request from the browser would likely time out as well. This really needs to be a background task...or make the socket connection direct from the browser without going via php. Depends on your requirements and scenario, of course